# How to print multipage HTML tables in different browsers

Tags: css, printing, cross-browser

What is the best practice to print a HTML table that contains cells with about 5cm height that should not be broken to different pages.

I already made print.css and definied

```
table { page-break-inside:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
thead { display:table-header-group }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

But :

- in Chrome the picture in the HTML page is split across pages
- in Firefox, the first page is empty, the table starts at the second page and the rest of the table is cut away (page 3 empty again)
- IE I did not dare to try yet

Comment: A demo to work with, would be nice... (jsFiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser support for the page-break CSS properties is spotty, especially on table parts. If you want to prevent page breaks within the content of a cell, I would suggest nesting the content in a div, and setting "page-break-inside: avoid;" on the div. If you need to support older browsers that don't implement the page-break-inside property at all, you should also set "display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" on the div.

Also, be aware that if the height of the printable area (that is, page height minus top and bottom margin) is less than the height of your cell content, then it's impossible for the browser to avoid breaking it unless it can somehow warp the fabric of space (maybe Firefox has a "-moz-" property for that?).